# postgresql command not executing successfully through java code

Tags: java, processbuilder, postgresql-9.5

I have installed the postgresql database and I have to fire few commands on this database through my java code. But the commands are not executing through java code. If I fire the same commands through command prompt they gets execute. Below is my java code:

```
   package frontend.guifx.pginstallation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyMultipleCommandsEx {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException{

        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();

        commands.add("CMD");
        commands.add("/c");
        commands.add("SET PGPASSWOR=test_admin");
        commands.add(psql.exe --dbname=postgres --username=test_admin --port=5433 --command="\"CREATE schema test;\"");

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\bin"));

        try {
            Process prs = pb.start();
            int e = prs.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Echo command executed, any errors? " + (e == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));

            System.out.println("Echo Output:\n" + output(prs.getInputStream())); 
             System.out.println("Error code:"+e);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: Why not use JDBC like normal people?

Comment: I have to do this through the command line only beacuse this is the postgresql installation task..I have installed the postgresql 9.5 through java code and now I have to execute the commands like creation of different roles over this DB and in the end I have to load one dump of data on this DB through java code.